# Fill down zeros for specific column where there are no values (Python)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a dataframe, df, where I would like to fill down zeroes in a specific column where there are no values.

Data

```
id  type    count   ppr
aa  cool    12      9
aa  hey             7
aa  hi      12      7
bb  no              7
bb  yes             7
```

Desired

```
id  type    count   ppr
aa  cool    12      9
aa  hey     0       7
aa  hi      12      7
bb  no      0       7
bb  yes     0       7
```

Doing

```
df['count'] = df.fillna(0).astype(int)
```

However, this only gives output of a single column and not the full dataset
Any suggestion is appreciated

Comment: Please, provide us an example of how we recreate this dataframe :)

Comment: So, you want to work on a single column (as in your question title) or multiple columns for the full dataset (as in the last paragraph of the question ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have no values, maybe it's because you have an empty string:

```
>>> df['count']
0    12
1
2    12
3
4
Name: count, dtype: object  # <- HERE
```

So, this should work:

```
df['count'] = df['count'].replace('', 0).astype(int)
```

```
>>> df
   id  type  count  ppr
0  aa  cool     12    9
1  aa   hey      0    7
2  aa    hi     12    7
3  bb    no      0    7
4  bb   yes      0    7
```

Answer (score 1):

`df['count']=df['count'].fillna(0).astype(int)`

Here is the code that worked for me (and that should have been added to the question to make solving it easier

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df_sample =\
pd.DataFrame([["day1","day2","day1","day2","day1","day2"],
              [None,160,None,180,110,None]] ).T

df_sample.columns = ["day","count"] 
df_sample['count']=df_sample['count'].fillna(0).astype(int)
print(df_sample)
```

Answer (score 1):

Seen from your sample code of `fillna()` that works for a single column. I suppose your "no values" are actually `NaN` values.

Further seen from your last paragraph that you mentioned difficulty in applying to the full dataset, I further suppose you want to apply to multiple columns.  As such, see below:

If you want to apply to ALL numeric type columns and try to change them to integer type if possible, you can try:

```
df.loc[:, df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns] = df.select_dtypes(include='number').fillna(0, downcast='infer')
```

**Demo**

```
# Before conversion:
print(df)

   id  type  count  ppr
0  aa  cool   12.0  9.0
1  aa   hey    NaN  7.0
2  aa    hi   12.0  NaN
3  bb    no    NaN  7.0
4  bb   yes    NaN  7.0

 df.loc[:, df.select_dtypes(include='number').columns] = df.select_dtypes(include='number').fillna(0, downcast='infer')

# After conversion:
print(df)

   id  type  count  ppr
0  aa  cool     12    9
1  aa   hey      0    7
2  aa    hi     12    0
3  bb    no      0    7
4  bb   yes      0    7
```